# How do I gain an organiser badge?

Tags: discussion

It says that you need to retag a question  to earn an organiser badge.
What does retag exactly mean? 
And how do i do it?

I tried editing my question and simply changing the tags, but that didnt earn me an organiser badge.

I probably didnt specifically understand the meaning of retag.

Some help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you understood the meaning of retag just fine. What the badge description doesn't make clear is that you only get the badge for retagging *somebody else*'s question (which requires at least 500 reputation, so you can't do it yet).

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-tag a question that someone else has asked not your own question.

The option to re-tag other questions is only available once you have [reached 500 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/retag-questions).

[A community maintained list of badges can be found here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258)